# What's the difference between a PageMod/page-mod and a Page/page-worker?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I don't understand the difference.  The only difference I can see is that a PageMod uses a match pattern, whereas a Page uses a specific URL.  Why not just use a PageMod (more versatile) for everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `page-mod` module works with pages that the user loads in the browser. The `page-worker` module lets *you* load a web page in the background and perform some operations with it. So you would for example use `page-mod` if you want to add a "Super-Dooper-Search" button to all Google Search pages when the user visits them. But you would use `page-worker` if you want to load the Google Search page in background when the user clicks some button, extract the search results from it and present the results to the user - without the user ever seeing the page you loaded (just as an example, don't actually do that because it violates Google's ToS).